# How to authenticate between Azure Functions and a dedicated App Service VM

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, cold-start

I have a `Function` app running in consumption plan. I enabled `ReadyToRun` compilation and targeted x64 on Windows. The problem is the bin folder has many dlls with a total size of 90 MBs. I want to minimize cold start times as much as possible.

I'm considering leveraging multiple apps (by adding multiple Function apps or a dedicated VM to process seldom-used logic). Is there any MS documentation out there on how I could authenticate between multiple apps? My Function app is using custom authentication right now with JWT. Once the user is authenticated via the main app, I'm thinking of invoking REST APIs in the other apps.

Comment: I would highly recommend splitting off your first question into a separate question, as it doesn't match the title, which will hurt the ability of people to find it, and it puts pressure on answers to address both questions, even if someone doesn't have expertise in both.

Comment: OK. Moved the first question to another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for your first question. However, I may be able to help with the second question. Have you been able to look into Durable Functions at all? It seems this would be your solution if you are looking to leverage multiple apps. See the link below for MSFT documentation on Durable Functions.

[Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp)

Using Durable Functions will allow you to orchestrate the logical flow of your multiple functions. You could then invoke the built-in HTTP APIs that use a generated key for authentication.

Hope this gives some help for your second question.

Comment: Is there any documentation I could look at to see how a generated key for authentication is used with Durable Functions?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking into the [Azure App Service Authentication/Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) (also known as EasyAuth) feature. If you are running your function app on an App Service plan, a Consumption plan, or the Premium plan (i.e. you are running it on the Azure Functions platform rather than hosting it on raw VMs or some other compute platform), you get this feature automatically.

[This resource](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/using-msal-net-to-call-an-azure-function-app-with-easy-auth-enabled/) describes how you can generate valid bearer tokens for an application protected with Easy Auth. Also note that if you are using an HTTP trigger with C#, you can get claims from the token just by adding an [additional parameter to your signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#working-with-client-identities).

Comment: I have to use custom authentication, so I can't use those auth providers. Also, I already have a working auth mechanism for my function app. Ideally, I'd like to avoid passing a token to the next app so that it validates the token with the database a second time. I was hoping to see if there is a way to invoke another app within Azure and "trust" it without going through tokens.